# Java never ending switch loop (sometimes) eclipse

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

Im completely puzzled by this one I have a switch statement inside a loop:

```
package com.example.project

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Keyserver {
static ServerSocket server;
static Socket soc;
static ObjectInputStream in;
static int key;
static Robot bot;
static boolean shift = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
    bot = new Robot();
    while(true){
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4321, 10);
            soc = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted port");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(soc.isConnected()){
            try {
                key = in.readInt();
                System.out.println(key);
                switch(key){
                case(7):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                    break;
                case(8):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    break;
                case(9):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    break;
                case(10):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                    break;
                                    ....
                case(53):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
                    break;
                case(54):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
                    break;
                case(4):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                    break;
                case(62):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                    break;
                case(59):
                    if(!shift){
                        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }else{
                        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                    shift = !shift;
                    break;
                case(60):
                    if(!shift){
                        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }else{
                        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                    shift = !shift;
                    break;

                case(90):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    break;
                case(91):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                    break;
                case(92):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                    break;
                case(93):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                    break;
                case(104):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    break;
                case(105):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                    break;
                case(106):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                    break;
                case(107):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
                    break;
                case(108):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    break;
                case(109):
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                    break;
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    e.toString();
                    in.close();
                    soc.close();
                    server.close();
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.toString();
                }   
            }
        }
        System.out.println("PORT CLOSED");
    }

}

}
```

everything works ok except for 90-93, they cause the program to loop forever until I click on eclipse then it stops.  It's not an eclipse problem because when I build it into a .jar I  got the same result and its not a server problem because when I made the button that sent the 90 send 7 it worked ok

it seems only 90-93 cause the infinite loop, I already tried changing the numbers from 90 to something like 200 but no luck

any enlightenment guys?

Comment: It is good idea to log/print info about exception thrown in try-catch. `e.toString()` will only return String with info about exception but you have to use it somewhere.

Comment: Does your `System.out.println(key);` line show the proper `readInt()` value?

Comment: @doublesharp thats the crazy thing, it outputs the right number once then it starts outputing another number- heres the catch when i send 90 it presses 1 then starts continuously reading 8 as the input which also presses 1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this code:

```
bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

is hanging for some reason.  Nothing to do with the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I figured it out.  You're not going to believe this one.

My servers a virtual android device- i wanted to make a remote keyboard app so i wrote the server to send every key press on my virtual keyboard to the client which would then emulate my keypress on my computer.

The problem?  It worked. My client would emulate a keypress on my computer which would then emulate a keypress on my android emulator (if you press a key on your keyboard it presses that key on the android keyboard) which would send the keypress to the client to press the key again, creating an infinite loop.

That explains why when i focused on the eclipse window and not the android window the server stopped receiving numbers, as the android device stopped receiving keypresses

Thanks for your guys's help though much appreciated